# Sorting a 3 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [szam] => 8
                    [index] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [szam] => 1
                    [index] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [szam] => 7
                    [index] => 1
                )

        )
```

I thought that my last cmp will work fine

```
function maxSzerintCsokkeno($item1,$item2)
{
    if ($item1['szam'] == $item2['szam']) return 0;
    return ($item1['szam'] < $item2['szam']) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

with foreach

```
foreach ($tomb as $kulcs => $adat)  usort($adat,"maxSzerintCsokkeno");
```

but it dosen't do anything, advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting a temporary variable, meaning the changes are not applied. The following should work for you:

```
for($i = 0, $length = count($tomb); $i < $length; $i++)
{
    usort($tomb[$i], "maxSzerintCsokkeno");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($tomb as $kulcs => $adat)  usort($adat,"maxSzerintCsokkeno");
```

This only sorts the subarray array $adat. And this only exists temporarily until foreach loops over the next one. The lazy option here would be to use a reference:

```
foreach ($tomb as & $adat)  usort($adat,"maxSzerintCsokkeno");
```

Notice the `&`. This way the modification on $adat will be applied directly in the parent array.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through the foreach loop, the key and value variables (`$kulcs` and `$adat` in your code) are copies of the actual values in the array.  Like Tim Cooper said, you are actually sorting a copy of the original value.

You can also pass the value by reference in your foreach loop.  This means that you will be modifying the original value:

```
foreach ($tomb as $kulcs => &$adat)  usort($adat,"maxSzerintCsokkeno");
```